# POST request hanging, mongodb and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

My `req.body` is successfully reaching the nested model in the mongodb database, but the console shows a hanging POST request (img below, the request shows the loading icon forever).

[image]

Here is how the route to update that data is set

`router.post('/api/teams/:tid/players', player.add);`

Then the mongodb add query which technically updates an existing Team but adds a new object to the players array within that model

```
add: function(req, res) {
    models.Team.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.tid }, { $addToSet: { players: req.body} }, function(err, doc){
              console.log(doc);
    });
}
```

My command line shows that the POST was a success 200
[image]

The POST request after a while goes red

[image]

So I hope this is a no brainer mistake I made, but my question is what is causing a rocky POST request, it works but it is not very smooth and needs to be fixed. It also doesn't make much sense, so I am hoping someone can point it out. It might have to do with my mongodb query, so let me show you my Team SCHEMA just to show you how I am adding into it.

```
var Team = new Schema({
    team_name:   { type: String },
    players: [
        {
            player_name:  { type: String },
            points:       { type: Number },
            made_one:     { type: Number },
            made_two:     { type: Number },
            made_three:   { type: Number },
            missed_one:   { type: Number },
            missed_two:   { type: Number },
            missed_three: { type: Number },
            percentage:   { type: Number },
            assists:      { type: Number },
            rebounds:     { type: Number },
            steals:       { type: Number },
            blocks:       { type: Number },
            fouls:        { type: Number },  
            feed:         { type: String },
            facebook_id:  { type: Number }
        }
    ],
    points:       { type: Number },
    made_one:     { type: Number },
    made_two:     { type: Number },
    made_three:   { type: Number },
    missed_one:   { type: Number },
    missed_two:   { type: Number },
    missed_three: { type: Number },
    percentage:   { type: Number },
    assists:      { type: Number },
    rebounds:     { type: Number },
    steals:       { type: Number },
    blocks:       { type: Number },
    fouls:        { type: Number },  
    feed: { type: String }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not sending any response in your request handler.

Comment: oh so I need to `res.json(doc)`

Comment: I just go by what I see, and I had some help with this query I didnt know I needed to send a res, I always did that but I didnt know it was necessary especially on POST requests, trying that now :)

Comment: Sucks I wrote this long question finding out I just needed to add `res.json(doc)` 13 charactures lol